# How do I convert my Jquery code to a StimulusJS controller Rails 7?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I'm building out a feature to show if the discount code in a text field is valid. I just managed to build it out using Jquery, but now I wanna convert it into a StimulusJS controller. But I'm not really sure how to.

My current view with jquery:

```
<div class="mt-2 mx-1">
 <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Discount Code</label>
 <div class="mt-1">
  <input type="text" name="discount_code" id="validateCode" class="appearance-none block w- 
  full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 
  focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-500 focus:border-teal-500 sm:text-sm">
 </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#validateCode').on("keyup", function(){
    let code = $('#validateCode').val()
    fetch('/choose_plan/validate_discount_code?code=' + code)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { if(data.valid)
      { $('#validateCode').css("background-color", "aliceblue") }
    else
      { $('#validateCode').css("background-color", "white") }
    });
  });
</script>
```

My validate_discount_controller.js I've started on:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="validate-discount"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      // execute a fetch request or something here
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in Stimulus, but if you have it working you may just want to move on to other things and refactor later if needed.

Nonetheless, here is a breakdown of how to convert your jQuery to vanilla (i.e. no library) JS and also Stimulus.

A great resource is this website - https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ or the Mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/

### jQuery breakdown

- `$('#validateCode').on("keyup", function(){`

  - For the most part you can avoid setting event listeners by using the `data-action` attribute - it is a very simple way to add event listeners for you.
  - e.g. `data-action="keyup->validate-discount#validate"` will call the controller's `validate` method on `keyup`.
  - See https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/actions
- `let code = $('#validateCode').val()`

  - Reading values from inputs can be done without jQuery by reading the element's `value' property.
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#methods
  - You can access the controller's element via `this.element`, so `this.element.value` is all you need.
- `{ $('#validateCode').css("background-color", "aliceblue") }...`

  - You can update the `style` on an element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style
  - However, it is probably better to use classes, Stimulus gives you a nice way to declare the classes for various 'states' you want to use and make them available in the controller.
  - https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/css-classes

### Example

```html
<form>
  <div class="mt-2 mx-1">
    <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" for="validateCode">Discount Code</label>
    <div class="mt-1">
      <input type="text" name="discount_code" id="validateCode" class="all-the-100-classes"
        data-controller="validate-discount" data-action="validate-discount#validate keyup->validate-discount#validate"
        data-validate-discount-valid-class="bg-error" data-validate-discount-invalid-class="bg-success">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note: I have included a [debounce](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/) script as you probably do not want to be calling the API every single keystroke - this is very likely going to cause frustration for your users and heavy load on your API. You may want to consider a [throttle](https://gomakethings.com/debouncing-vs.-throttling-with-vanilla-js/) approach instead.

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

// https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
};

export default class extends Controller {
  // https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/css-classes
  static classes = ['invalid', 'valid'];

  // https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/values
  static values = {
    endpoint: {
      default: '/choose_plan/validate_discount_code?code=',
      type: String,
    },
  };

  initialize() {
    // this will ensure that the API does not get called too much
    // the wait time (300) is in milliseconds so adjust as needed
    this.validate = debounce(this.validate.bind(this), 300);
  }

  validate() {
    // read the value from the input
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement
    const code = this.element.value;

    fetch('/choose_plan/validate_discount_code?code=' + code)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ valid }) => {
        if (valid) {
          this.element.classList.remove(...this.invalidClasses);
          this.element.classList.add(...this.validClasses);
        } else {
          this.element.classList.add(...this.invalidClasses);
          this.element.classList.remove(...this.validClasses);
          this.element.setCustomValidity('Thats incorrect!');
        }

        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setCustomValidity
        this.element.reportValidity();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to use tailwind color classes for it to work instead of bg-error/success. Apart from that it worked perfectly :)

Comment: What if I'd wanted to add an svg icon instead of changing the bg/border color?